# Making hyperlinks stay the same colour even after they have been clicked

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, colors

My links show up as the purple 'clicked' shade but I would like them to stay white even after being clicked.

My HTML:

```
<div id="top_nav">
    <ul id="top_links">
        <li><a href= "null">Hello Guest :</a></li>
        <li><a href="null"> Login :</a></li>
        <li><a href="null"> Sign Up:</a></li>
        <li><a href="null"> Help: </a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
#top_nav li {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: inline;
color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE This code -

```
#top_nav li a:visited{
    color:inherit
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#top_nav li a:visited {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use to specify the anchor pseudo-classes a:link,a:visited,a:active.

```
#top_nav li a:link,
#top_nav li a:visited, 
#top_nav li a:active { 
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     display: inline;
     color: white;
}
```